# ものなら's relationship to もの+なら?

Tags: conditionals

Consider

> 夜遅く帰ろう**ものなら**、家に入れてもらえません
>
> If I come home late, he won't let me in.

Is ものなら its own word/grammar point, or is it just もの＋なら? E.g.:

> **If you're speaking of the thing of me coming home late**, he won't let let me in!

If it really is just もの＋なら, then why isn't it

> 「夜遅く帰ろう**ことなら**、家に入れてもらえません」 （ことなら）

or

> 「夜遅く帰ろう**のなら**、家に入れてもらえません」 （のなら）

instead? It seems like "coming home" is more akin to an abstract object (こと) than a concrete one (もの), no?

Comment: AFAICT, structurally it is もの+なら, but it has become a set expression. I don't know why it uses もの, but it's listed in Jisho written with the kanji 物, so....

Comment: Normally, a volitional form doesn’t directly modify a noun (or nominalizer) like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is of coure もの＋なら, but the usage is particular to [ものなら](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE%E3%81%AA%E3%82%89/#jn-219924) and does not extend to other equivalent combinations. As the following says, it means *In case (something undesirable) happens...*

> ［接助］《形式名詞「もの」＋断定の助動詞「だ」の仮定形「なら」から》動詞・動詞型助動詞の連体形に付く。
>
> ２ （「うものなら」「ようものなら」「まいものなら」の形で）もし実現したら、好ましくない事態が起こる場合を仮定的に示す意を表す。…としたら。「うそをつこう―、とんでもない目にあうぞ」「うっかり捨てよう―、どやされるぜ」